# Matplotlib How to change length of line

Tags: python, matplotlib, line

Can you please help, how to change my code, so the red line will be longer and connect black point?

```
data.plot(kind = "scatter", x = "Pocet.potvrdenych", y = "Pocet.umrti")
plt.plot(x, model1.predict(x), color = "r", linewidth = 5)
plt.scatter(novi_potvrdeni, umrti, color="black")
```

[image: Graph picture]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the site [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Also, try to create a minimal viable example, don't forget to import the relevant libraries.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you advice :)

Comment: Define `x_fit = np.linspace(0, x_of_black_dot, 1000)`, then use `x_fit` instead of x in the `plt.plot()` line?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the second line to:

```py
plt.plot(x + novi_potvrdeni, model1.predict(x) + umrti,
    color = "r", linewidth = 5)
```

Comment: Hi Roman, thanks for your advise:) Can you please advice , after applying your code, I cant see my line at all

Comment: @Katka, that is strange, it just adds your black point to the list of points defining your red line. Maybe try this if one of `x`, `model1.predict(x)`, `novi_potvrdeni` or `umrti` are not lists: `plt.plot(list(x) + list(novi_potvrdeni), list(model1.predict(x)) + list(umrti), color = "r", linewidth = 5)` BTW is this something with neural networks and Slovak corona epidemics? Is your code somewhere on github?